# Where is the ordering of taskbar shortcuts stored?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts

In Windows, where is the "ordering" of the taskbar program shortcut icons stored?

I'm trying to rearrange them without directly click-and-dragging them into a respective arrangement. Behind the scenes, all I can find is the folder where these shortcuts are stored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortcuts themselves can be found in the following folders:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu
```

Their order is stored in the following REG_BINARY value:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband\Favorites
```

I don't think it's going to be easy to edit the ordering directly. What you can do is [enumerate all the pinned shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840456/get-list-of-links-pinned-to-the-taskbar) and unpin them, then [pin what you want](https://superuser.com/questions/607481/automate-creation-of-taskbar-shortcuts) in the required order.